# Java how to detect whether a hashmap has changed after some time or operations?

Tags: java

I want to record a HashMap's state in a point of time.
Then user might or might not change it, and when they click a button,
I want to compare the HashMap's state to the previously saved state and see whether there has been any changes.

Can I do

```
String firstState = map.toString();
```

then

```
String secondState = map.toString();
```

and then compare whether they are equal?

EDIT: By state I mean something that will change if anything about the HashMap changes

Comment: Define "state", is it (key,value)? Or just key? Or maybe only value?

Comment: By saying State --> you mean size ?

Comment: you could use a Observer pattern?

Comment: By state I mean something that will change if anything about the HashMap changes

Comment: actually I've did something like this some years ago :-) I've called it something like "HashMapWithMemory". I don't remember well what was the requirement for this, but I remember I had to compare the current hashmap with the previous one. What I've did was to extend HashMap, keep another HashMap as an attribute and intercept/override all the relevant HashMap methods (add/addAll/remove/removeAll/etc) to do the trick. Certainly not thread-safe, but it worked for me. Unfortunately I don't have the code anymore, but this was my approach at that time. I also remember it was painful :-)

Comment: Maybe. Two equal objects might have no own toString, but Object.toString (differing). Putting an equal value into the map then gives a difference. Also Map.toString is expensive. **Wrap the map in your own Map registering changes** - `put``, `putAll`, `remove` ...

Comment: If your map was modified several times but end up in the exact same state, do you consider it a change? I mean, if you add a key/value pair and then remove it, the map is identical, yet do you consider it a change?

Comment: Other question: if an object in your map is mutated, do you consider it a change of state for your map?

Comment: first question - no, second  -yes

Comment: This Question is AMBIGUOUS.  It is UNCLEAR whether the OP wants to detect if changes have been made, or if the current state of the maps is (currently) the same.

Comment: ANY CHANGE in the map needs to be detected. what is ambiguous about this.

Comment: Again ambiguous, what precisely is meant by a change?  And are you really talking about a change ... or a difference?  (And DO NOT tell me that those two things mean the same thing.  They don't!!)

Comment: @J.K. I totally agree with Stephen C. Look at my comments for examples of what you should clarify. Do you consider as changes some mutations on the objects contained in the map? Do you consider the map has changed if there were some modifications but the maps ends up in the same state?

Comment: And did you not see my answer to your questions right below them?

Comment: @J.K. my apologies, I must have missed your comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to tell if something was really changed is to make a copy of the map, and compare that to the map at a later time:

```
HashMap<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
// Populate map...

// Save the state:
HashMap<String, String> saved = new HashMap<>(m);

// Clients might modify map here...

// Test if the map was modified:
boolean modified = saved.equals(m);
```

`HashMap.hashCode()` can only be used to tell if the map **did** changed (if the hashcode changes). If the hashcode doesn't change, it is not a guarantee that the map was not changed.

Wrapping the map and overriding the `put()` and `clear()` methods for example also not enough, because if someone changes a value with `put()`, it could be that later he will call `put()` again and set the old value which you are not storing anymore and can't tell if the same old value is restored.

**Proving the hascode-based method wrong:**

If the map contains `String`s as values for example, we can change a value to a different `String` having the same hashcode easily, that way `HashMap.hashCode()` won't change.

For example the following `String`s all have the same hashcode yet they are not equal:

```
String s1 = "";      // Hashcode = 0
String s2 = "\0";    // Hashcode = 0
String s3 = "\0\0";  // Hashcode = 0

HashMap<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("one", s1);
m.put("one", s2); // This does not change m.hashCode() yet its content changes!
```

**Proving the wrapper-based method wrong:**

```
HashMap<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("one", "1");

// Now "save" state and modify the map via a wrapper

Map<String, String> w = ...; // Create a wrapper

w.put("one", "2"); // This will trigger that map is modified
w.put("one", "1"); // This will trigger that map is modified, yet it is restored

// Now the contents of the map is identical to the state that was saved.
```

Comment: I think last part of the proof is not correct - the restoration is also a modification. Isn't it?

Comment: Your second example "proving the wrapper wrong" is actually proof that it worked correctly.

Comment: Well, it depends on the "definition" of whether the map is modified. After that restoration, the contents of the map will be identical to the original one.

Comment: this is NOT the answer to the original question

Comment: @injecteer It actually is, at least now

Comment: Other proof that the wrapper is wrong: if you mutate an object referenced by the map, the wrapper won't detect it, yet the content of the map changed. (This depends on how the OP defines the "state" of the map)

Comment: Most wrappers don't provide a way of directly accessing the internal implementation, hence the concept of "wrapping" it. If you're going to provide a way to access the internal implementation, than you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I changed the code slightly. I didn't want to elaborate on wrapper, just wanted to show an example when it will say the map was changed even though its content will be identical (or in general equal) to the original content.

Comment: I apologize icza, I didn't understand what OP wanted and commented based on what I thought he said. For OP's purposes you were right about proving the mapper wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare its' hash values

```
int hash1 = map.hashCode();
// do something
int hash2 = map.hashCode();
```

the JavaDoc states:

> > The hash code of a map is defined to be the sum of the hash codes of each entry in the map's entrySet() view

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  There is a chance that you will change the map, and yet the hashcode will still be the same.

Comment: This is not a good answer. This can only be used to tell if the map **did** change (if the hashcode changes). If the hascode remains the same, it is not a guarantee that the map didn't change.

Comment: Flip the values of two items in the hashtable. Same hashcode, but you've made a change to the table. This answer, frankly, is wrong.

Comment: and the purpose of such flip? just for fun?

Comment: @injecteer see the "proof that the hashcode-based method is wrong" in icza's answer.

Comment: anyway, for implementing the "normal" "business logic" it's the most simple and performant solution. If needed it can be easily extended

Comment: @injecteer - sorry, but are saying that a solution that sometimes (unpredictably) gives the wrong answer is a good solution?  Really?  Remind me never to put my money in a Bank that employs you as a programmer!

Comment: @Stephen-c what is your definition of `sometimes`? The solution fails with primitive types of keys and values and only in a very certain case. So, if I know, that no flip should ever occur: for example, I want to create a mapping `id -> objectFromTheDBById`, then the solution is just fine. Of course, for the home-assignment with flipping primitives I'd invest more time for solving the "flipping primitives" problem ;)

Comment: Sometimes == with a probability greater than zero.  And it is not only in restricted cases that you can somehow work around.  For any pair of randomly generated Java objects **of any type**, the chance of the two objects having the same hashcode is AT LEAST 1 in 2^32.  For many classes the probability will be larger.

Comment: @injecteer your solution may be right for some problems (where collisions can't occur) but you have to admit that you can't tell if it is the case for the OP's problem without more information.

Comment: @joffrey Indeed, and I admitted it twice :)

Comment: (I'm not referring to the "flipping" problem.  I'm referring to the case where different keys/values have the same hashcodes.  And then there is the case where the key/value hashcodes are different, but the hash of the hashcodes is the same anyway.  And the latter is really difficult to avoid.  You have to analyse all of the possible combinations of keys/values to determine if a collision is possible.)

Comment: you must really try hard to get the same hashcodes for different objects, given the correctness of their `hashCode()` implementations. Of course, the probability of such event is >0, but the whole Java-world can somehow cope with this drawback, cann't it?

Comment: Nope.  The maths says that the best-case probability is one in 2^32.  It will eventually without anyone trying.  But worse than that, unless you analyse the hash functions and the "space" of keys / values, you don't know if the probability isn't significantly larger than that.  And nope, a probability of an incorrect answer of that order is NOT acceptable in many, many applications.

Comment: so, you want to say, that the whole java community suffers a lot from the improper `hashCode()` concept?

Comment: @injecteer Hard to get same hashcode for different objects? Try these 2 strings: `""` and `"\0"`. They are different, and both have `0` hashcode.

Comment: look a bit beyond primitive types ok? you can easily find the unicode representations for any symbol, which would give exactly the same hashcode. so what?

Comment: @injecteer I don't really understand why you struggle on details (such as primitive types or not) while the very concept of your solution is not working on its own. Hash collisions can occur for a map's hash in almost every situation, in particular because, as you stated, the hash of a map is the sum of the entries hashes.

Comment: @injecteer I'm not completely throwing away your solution. I'm just saying that, if the hash is the same, then you have to further investigate by a method such as icza's.

Comment: Tracking and comparing the map size probably would make this slightly more effective as well, right?

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can just wrap the map into a wrapper class which records the last modified time,  whatever. Using the value, you might check if there was a modification.

If you decide to use hashCode value to solve this problem, you should ignore the possibility that there might be a hash collision.

But in answering question, I think there's one important aspect to consider - the number of keys. If there are not too many keys, the 'copy construction + equals' method will be a good alternative to the wrapper-based solution. (make and old copy first, and later compare it with the current state of the map) But if there are too many keys, the two operations might incur large overhead.

Comment: This is not a useful answer. Please explain the advantage this solution provides over @injecteer's, which requires no extra code.

Comment: Good comment. In a very rare case, I thought that there might be a hash value collision, because it's int (32 bit). Of course, I admit it's a very rare case.

Comment: Same to you :) Add that to your answer, and it's worth leaving up.

Comment: @bjlee72 - The "rarity" depends on the quality of the key/value hash functions and the object distributions whether a hash collision occurs.  It may be 1 in 2^32.  Or it may be more frequent.

Comment: @StephenC - Right. depends on distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of the map.

```
HashMap old = new HashMap(map);
```

Then checks if the old map contains the same key/value bindings as the current map, assuming that 'equals' is correctly implemented for values.

```
if (!old.equals(map)) {
    System.out.println("Something changed");
}
```